# extracting data from div tags Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage that has some of the data nested in div tags.

```
url = 'http://london2012.fiba.com/pages/eng/fe/12/olym/p/gid/26/grid/A/rid/9087/sid/6233/game.html'
boxurl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(boxurl)

linescoreA = soup.find("div", {"class": "scoreA"})

print linescoreA
```

outputs this:

```
<div class="scoreA">
<div class="period">19</div>
<div class="period">22</div>
<div class="period">22</div><div class="period">26</div>
<div class="final">89</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and that is where I get stuck.  How do I get the data from the div tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get just the textual data, use [`.stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
print list(linescoreA.stripped_strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for node in soup.find("div", {"class": "scoreA"}):
    print ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))
```

and what about

```
for node in soup.find("div", {"class": "scoreA"}):
        print node.string
```

I am sorry, i cannot try for you.